# How to run batch jobs in Python with a pool of resources?

Tags: python

I have to call around 100 C++ long-running programs (many times), which can be both CPU and IO heavy.

I'm doing the calling from Python using Popen. With my current naive approach:

```
for exe in all_exe:
    processes.append(Popen(exe))

while not completed(processes):
    sleep(1.0)
```

my system's resources get exhausted very quickly. Is there a Python
library that would allow me to specify how many workers out of 100 I
want to run at once (since running all at once is bad), that would
start a new worker as soon as the old one completes?

Maybe also with some options like `nice` and `ionice`, so that I can
make the most use of my system's resources without experiencing
slowdowns.

Comment: Technically you're not supposed to ask about links to libraries or such, but the fact that you have so many processes that take so much CPU effort has left me flabbergasted.  Perhaps it would be best to split this up between many machines instead of one machine with a batch process?

Comment: You can test [Celery](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) which is a distributed task queue, I'm not sure about it since Celery is thread based but it's easy to to test and check.

Comment: Why are you reinventing the wheel? Python already has [process pools](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.pool) in his standard library.

Comment: @Bakuriu, that looks fine. Is that the standard approach? I'm not a Python person, and I don't want to reinvent the wheel, just want to know why people typically use for this. Also, what about `nice` and `ionice`? Can process pools be configured in that way?